# Spring boot doesn't run scheduler @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cache, spring-cloud-gateway

I used in my project configuration bean for cache evict and it's not runs. I use this some class in another projects and works fine but I don't know where is the problem now.

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class CacheConfig {

    public static final String BANKCODE_CACHE_NAME = "cacheName";

    @CacheEvict(allEntries = true, cacheNames = { CACHE_NAME })
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void cachePosEvict() {
        log.info("Evicting cache: {}", CACHE_NAME);
    }

}
```

Problem is probably somewhere else with this config bean, because also when I use:

```
@PostConstruct
void init() {
    log.info("Init...");
}
```

Then is nothing in log. I looked into TRACE spring logs and there is no error, class is in the classpath.
I don't know where can be a problem.

I have following dependencies in gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR6")
    webfluxUiVersion = "1.3.9"
    jacksonVersion = "2.10.1"
    logbackJson = "0.1.5"
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:${webfluxUiVersion}"


    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:${jacksonVersion}"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${jacksonVersion}"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:${jacksonVersion}"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:${jacksonVersion}"

    implementation "ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-json-classic:${logbackJson}"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-jackson:${logbackJson}"
```

I use Java 11 with Main class:

```
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApp{...}
```

**EDIT:** I found that problem is in my configuration:

```
main:
    lazy-initialization: true
```

I thought that bean will be created when Scheduler is active.

Comment: I think your class should be annotated with `@Component` and not `@Configuration`

Comment: The `@Configuration` class doesn't have a `@Component` annotation, why should it run `@PostConstruct`? I think `@Scheduled` method need to be in `@Component` classes as well.

Comment: [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) is an `@Component`, just like `@Service`. Now that doesn't mean he should use `@Configuration` in this case. I suspect due to the `@Configuration` a double proxy is being created (config classes are processed very specifically) and the `@CacheEvict` leads to a proxy as well.

Comment: Can you make sure that the package of the class falls under ComponentScan of the application?

Comment: saurabhkedia I think that it doesn't matter in this case if there is annotation {@Configuration} or {@Component}. Yes, class is under componentScan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was in disable feature:

```
spring:
   main:
     lazy-initialization: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a webflux, you might need to return a publisher (Mono or Flux) that can be subscribed to, for example:

```
public Mono<Void> cachePosEvict() {
    log.info("Evicting cache: {}", CACHE_NAME);
}
```

Comment: I thought that you are right, but it doesn't work :-(     ```public Mono<Void> cachePosEvict() {
        log.info("Evicting cache: {}", BANKCODE_CACHE_NAME);
        return Mono.empty();```
    }

Comment: Yeah, I tested it out afterwards and it works fine without a return type. I wonder if task is executing, but log statement isn't working for some reason. Maybe try instantiating a logger the old Java way instead of using Lombok.

Comment: It's not there, also /actuator/scheduledtasks seems empty.

Answer (score 0):

You periodically evict all entries from your cache. Either you have a very specific use case or you're doing it wrong.

I assume that you use Caffeine implementation. In this case consider configuring cache expiration through a dedicated property:

```
spring.cache.caffeine.spec=expireAfterWrite=5s
```

More information here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#cache-properties

Comment: It's interesting I didn't know about it. Yes, I would like to evict all entries. But my problem is not in  @CacheEvict, but probably something wrong with bean. Another beans work well.

Comment: Does all your classes use `@Slf4j` ? Maybe Lombok somehow conflicts with Spring ?

Comment: Also in 99% of cases expiring the relevant item is the correct way - evicting all entries as a scheduled action just makes no sense.